# How come my shaded smooth model looks sharp?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

My model is shaded smooth, and autosmoothed. But some edges/faces look sharp. How come? And how do I fix it?

Comment: it may be the artefact called Terminator Effect, since 2.9 you can easily fix it, just tweak the *Shadow Terminator Offset* value in the *Properties panel > Object > Shading*

Comment: Oh I see, so it brings the shadow line closer to the light source so the shadow covers the artifact and smooth shading is applied or something like that?

Comment: I don't think it works this way but I can't tell exactly   ;)